# Searching a Custom ListView with ImageView not fitlering image

Tags: android

I am working on a project where there is a custom listview with imageview and a textview on top of the imageview.I have done the following code for filtering.

The main Fragment:

```
CategoriesAdapter adapter;
edt_SearchBar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s);

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

The CategoriesAdapter class:

```
public class CategoriesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<CategoryDataModel> category_list,category_filter_list;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    ViewHolder vh;
    ValueFilter filter;
    int counter=0;
    String[] images_array;

    public CategoriesAdapter(List<CategoryDataModel> category_list, Context context) {
        this.category_list=category_list;
        this.category_filter_list=category_list;
        this.context=context;
        inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader= AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        images_array=new String[]{"kochi_cinepolis.png","kochi_padma.png"};
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return category_list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return category_list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_view_style, null);
            vh=new ViewHolder();
            if (imageLoader == null)
                imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
            vh.imageView = (NetworkImageView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.imageView_grid);
            vh.categoryName= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvcategory);
            convertView.setTag(vh);
        }
        else
        {
            vh=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }



        vh.imageView.setImageUrl(AppConstant.IMAGE_FOLDER +images_array[position], imageLoader);

        vh.imageView.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.default_category_loading);

        vh.categoryName.setText(category_list.get(position).getCategory_name().toUpperCase());

        return convertView;
    }
    public class ViewHolder
    {
        NetworkImageView imageView;
        TextView categoryName;
    }
    public ValueFilter getFilter() {
        if(filter==null) {

            filter=new ValueFilter();
        }

        return filter;
    }

    public class ValueFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterResults results=new FilterResults();
            if(constraint!=null && constraint.length()>0){
                String cons_value=constraint.toString();

                List<CategoryDataModel> filterList=new ArrayList<>();

                for(int i=0;i<category_filter_list.size();i++){

                    if(category_filter_list.get(i).getCategory_name().toLowerCase().contains(cons_value.toLowerCase())) {

                        filterList.add(category_filter_list.get(i));

                    }
                }


                results.count=filterList.size();

                results.values=filterList;

            }else{

                results.count=category_filter_list.size();

                results.values=category_filter_list;

            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            category_list=(List<CategoryDataModel>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }
}
```

**The issue is the following.Now i have two items in the listview.I am searching the listview based on the text in the textview.But when the search results are returned the corresponding image of the row of the listview is shown wrongly.The image of the first row is what that is shown instead of the correct row.Please help at the earliest.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Adapter needs to implement Filterable interface and it has to implement getFilter() and than you need to override getFilter() in your custom adapter and filter the data source accordingly and notify the listview that the dataset has changed.

Comment: I tried implementing Filterable interface and using the overriden getFilter() method.The issue still persists.

Comment: I fixed the issue.The list for setting text,and setting image should be the same as the filtered list.I cannot use a list separate for the image.